# Curiosity about Id values - relates to hacking risks where Id values are guessed

Tags: salesforce-id

Yes `Id` values that a user should not have access to should be blocked at the database level using sharing rules.

But I'm curious about the starting value of an `Id`. From this tiny sample:

- First few Campaigns Ids in an org:

  - 7017g000000lDwn, 7017g000000lDx2, 7017g000000lDx7
- First few custom objects in an org:

  - a0h7g000008ASYa, a0h7g000008ASYf, a0h7g000008ASYk

it looks like the first Id value isn't "0" but instead is an unpredictable value by design or as a side effect having multiple machines as part of an org where each machine owns a range of values. Anyone have insight into this?

I'm also curious why the Id values are typically 5 apart e.g. 2->7, a->f, f->k?

Comment: The risk would depend on how it's used and the layer(s) of security, yeah? If you have GET /blah/rest/<id> endpoint, it runs as system and your app allows anyone to hit the endpoint, then you're exposed. See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html for an example of this vulnerability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Record ID values are globally unique per pod/instance (except for Sandboxes, see the end). Each system that works in the pod requests ID values in chunks from a global counter for every prefix. The exact system is proprietary, but suffice it to say that, in normal circumstances, records of the same object type in the same pod created by the same user in the same transaction will have serially incremented ID values.

Here's a quick example in Execute Anonymous:

```
Account[] a = new Account[0];
for(integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    a.add(new account(name='demo'));
}
insert a;
system.debug(new map<id, account>(a).keySet());
Assert.fail();
```

Which the log shows:

```
001Hs00002oiuIaIAI, 001Hs00002oiuIbIAI, 001Hs00002oiuIcIAI, 001Hs00002oiuIdIAI, 001Hs00002oiuIeIAI
```

As you can see, I get the unique values `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e` for this sample transaction (fourth character on the right).

The first three characters are a key prefix. Standard objects use values like `001`, `003`, `500`, `701`, and so on. Starting from `a00`, these represent custom objects. The same prefix `a00` does not correspond to the same object across orgs. In my org, it is a "Package", but in your org, it might be a "License" (or anything else). The prefixes increment the same as record ID values for each successive custom object in an org.

Remember that ID values are allocated in chunks to individual app servers. If you have several transactions within a few seconds of each other, you may end up with ID values that are really close to each other (e.g. 2 -> 7, a->f, f->k). That's more of a coincidence than anything.

ID values are assigned in ascending order per chunk, but multiple users can be on different machines within the org, and thus have different chunks. Let's say that user A inserts record 1 at time Y, then user B inserts record 2 at time Z, which is later than Y. It is possible for 1 to have a higher ID value than 2, assuming that the respective ID pools haven't been exhausted. In some orgs with low traffic, this may be common, while orgs with high traffic probably won't see this very often.

ID values are never reused on a pod, even if a record is deleted, fails to save successfully (e.g. because of an after-insert `addError` call), or was part of a unit test (and thus rolled back). The algorithm is deterministic in the sense that ID values are allocated serially. The exception to this rule are sandboxes, since sandboxes can clone records, and those ID values may duplicate values in production, and multiple sandboxes may end up on the same instance.

It's also possible that, for example, `7017g000000lDwn` belongs to your org, but `7017g000000lDwo` belongs to another org, since both users in two different orgs happened to be on the same app server and created a campaign record within a few milliseconds of each other. So, while it's possible to serially increment values to hope to find other records, it's a very large address space (62<sup>10</sup>) to search through, and those ID values are split across dozens or hundreds of orgs.

Comment: Thanks - helpful stuff. Note sure why I'm getting increments of 5 vs your increments of 1. Any thoughts on the starting number? I don't remember ever seeing a number close to zero.

Comment: @KeithC Only records that are very old have small ID values, as far as I'm aware. Salesforce's main org is "Org62", which has an ID of `00D000000000062`, for example, and it was created probably in 1999. I believe that whenever they do an org split for load-balancing purposes, the global counters are also copied (the ID values are disambiguated by the fourth and fifth character in an ID), so newer instances would never have such small numbers. Even my dev org from 2007 has four significant digits. despite surviving at least two migrations (na3->na184->na236).